# Red dust around the negative terminal of the battery

Tags: battery, dust

Today I noticed some red dust around the negative terminal of the battery.

**What could be the reason for this phenomenon, and is it a problem? Should I clean it up?**

I originally thought about corrosion, but apparently (after some Google search) corrosion is supposed to create some *white dust* around the *positive* terminal.

See attached picture.

[image: Red dust around the negative terminal]

Answer (score 3):

That looks to be copper anti-seize that was sprayed on your battery terminals.  This is to protect against corrosion as well as preventing the battery cables from seizing onto the battery terminals.  Below is a link to what I am mentioning.

[https://www.amazon.com/Lubricant-Automotive-Antisieze-Neversieze-BustApart/dp/B08ZFW771F/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08ZFW771F)

Comment: I'm sure that product was not used (I installed the battery myself), but at one point I sprayed WD-40 on the terminal, when I had to temporarily disconnect it. Could that also be the reason? And if yes, is it anything to worry about, or is ok like this? (If the residue WD40 protects against corrosion, then it is even better to leave it I guess?)

Comment: There is also WD40 with some copper in it https://www.amazon.co.uk/WD-40-300-ANTI-SEIZE-COPPER-GREASE/dp/B003GXHC2M please check the can.